# Separation of points clouds via classification methods

Tags: r, classification, clustering, discriminant-analysis, image-processing

I have multiple images from a 3D-Scanner in point cloud form. Part of the image is a fixture to hold the object to be scanned. I want to extract the object itself by classifying the fixture and the object in two separate classes = estimating a discriminant hyperplane, that cuts the cloud exactly at the points where the fixture touches the object.

2D Image of an SVM estimation (via the excellent klaR package) as an example:
[image] 
Some bullet points about the external conditions:

- The objects vary in shape and size.
- The position of the fixture varies a bit between images, since it is flexible
- The origin of the images varies, since the calibration is sometimes off (due to temparature changes etc.)

**The problem resulting from this**:

The absolute position of an estimated hyperplane is the same, independent of the data. The point, where the point cloud of the object ends and the point cloud of the fixture begins, varies,  but this is the point where the hyperplane is needed in every picture. Optimally, they would change position dependent on the data.

Some bullet points about what i have tried so far:

- Despite knowing I exclude myself from excellent libraries such as PCL, I use R
- Clustering works rather badly, since the point where the fixture touches the object is too large so it separates them not very well.
- LDA, QDA, RPart, KNN and SVMLight give me between 70-90% accuracy when comparing to a manual classification, when centering and standardizing the images by themselves

**My Question(s):**

What would you propose could be done about the fix hyperplanes? Do you think one could derive some sort of parameter from the image so the planes will be moved accordingly?

Is there maybe another Discriminant analysis method, that would be better suited here, preferrably with an R implementation?

Is there a feature that i should calculate, that could help me in the separation when added as a discriminating variable?

Comment: What do you mean by "The point where they are needed varies"? Also I think you mean "fixed" and not "fix" here.

Comment: The absolute position of an estimated hyperplane is the same, independent of the data. The point, where the point cloud of the object ends and the point cloud of the fixture begins, varies. This is the point where the hyperplane is needed. English is not my first language, do you think when describing the scenario i just explained "fixed" would be better? In that case, feel free to edit :)

Comment: in that case it does sound like you need a richer model, but I don't see how a discriminant analysis would help. You would have the same problem.

Comment: Did you try searching online? I found a lot of specialized websites when I searched for "object boundary detection."

Comment: As is so often the case, searching for the right keyword is the biggest hurdle - i searched for a lot of different keywords but not boundary detection, i had no idea this was a "thing". When researching it right now, it seems to me that most of it focuses on vision data, meaning grid data for grey scale and color images. Boundary feature extraction from point clouds seem much more rare, especially in the R community. The PCL libraries has some good ones, but there is no backend for R afaik. I will continue searching though, many thanks.

Comment: Regarding the use for DA: My basic idea is/was, that a 4th feature (additional to the 3 spatial coordinates) based on e.g. local density, local normals or something more complex could boost detection rates because the hyperplane would separete more observations correctly in the 4th dimension.